# How to handle error propagation and cutoff condition in infinite lists?

Tags: haskell

Given the following definitions

```
-- data, finite
dataFin :: Either String [[Int]]
dataFin = Right [[1..10]]

-- data, infinite
dataInf :: Either String [[Int]]
dataInf = Right [[1..]]

-- function applied to data
fun :: Int -> Either String Int
fun x = if x < 0 then Left "error" else Right $ x+1

-- next stage of processing, short circuiting on error
ns :: Either String [[Int]] -> (Int -> Either String Int) -> Either String [[Int]]
ns l f = l >>= traverse (traverse f)

-- condition for data cutoff
con :: Int -> Bool
con = (< 5)

-- results of processing
resultFin :: Either String [[Int]]
resultFin = ns dataFin fun

resultInf :: Either String [[Int]]
resultInf = ns dataInf fun
```

I can readily apply the cutoff condition to  elements of the finite result

```
λ> (fmap . fmap) (takeWhile con) resultFin
Right [[2,3,4]]
```

But for infinite data this hangs:

```
λ> (fmap . fmap) (takeWhile con) resultInf
```

How should this be done correctly for infinite data given Haskell's lazy nature? In particular, given that the condition `con` is applied to processed data, where and how should I incorporate it?

EDIT.

I was able to develop a (temporary) solution, but I am still very much interested in what would be a "correct" way of doing this. Here is the current version. Defining a "next stage" function that incorporates the cutoff condition

```
nsCond :: Either String [[Int]]
  -> (Int -> Either String Int)
  -> (Int -> Bool)
  -> Either String [[Int]]
nsCond d f c =
  d >>= (\ls ->
           let
             pls = (fmap . fmap) f ls :: [[Either String Int]] 
             wpls = fmap (takeWhile (\v -> case v of
                                            Left _ -> True
                                            Right x -> c x)) pls :: [[Either String Int]]
           in
             traverse sequence wpls)
```

we have, for the infinite data

```
λ> nsCond dataInf fun con
Right [[2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

To determine, wether `resultInf` is `Left` or `Right` the whole infinite list needs to be processed.

And you need to determine, wether `resultInf` is `Left` or `Right`, as soon as you try to use it in a nontrivial way.

Here it tries to determine wether it is `Left` or `Right` to print it.

If you try to use that value, you will probably try to pattern match on it, which will try to put it into WHNF, which means, the value will be computed to the first data constructor, which is the `Left` or `Right`.

Let's look at a simplified example:

```
infiniteList = [0..]
dataInf = traverse fun infiniteList
```

using `dataInf` in some nontrivial way will already hang, because the `traverse fun` part asks, wether every element in the list is non negative and to answer this question one has to look at every element of the list.

```
take 4 <$> dataInf
```

is asking for the first 4 elements of the list, if every element of the infinite list was non negative, otherwise for the error which occurred while checking the infinite list.

Comment: I understand that it does not work, but I also understand now that my question was badly formulated and did not reflect my real life problem. I have a cutoff condition for the processed infinite data, and the real question is how to incorporate this condition into processing.

Comment: Even if you short circuite on the error, how to determine, there is no error? So that the data constructor will be `Right`? You will have to look at each element of the infinite list.

Comment: Sure, but that does not address the new question. Given that two `traverse`s are such a convenient way to handle error propagation, at which point and how do I need to "intercept" the infinite list?

Comment: I updated my answer. you can't retroactively make `traverse` work on a finite number of elements, that would change the semantics of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the traverse and takeWhile function to create a new function traverseWhile as below

```
traverseWhile::Monad m =>(a->Bool)->(a->m a)->[a]->m [a]
traverseWhile _ _ [] = pure []
traverseWhile p h (x:xs) = (h x) >>= loop xs
    where loop ys y | p y       = (:) <$> pure y <*> traverseWhile p h ys
                    | otherwise = pure []
```

As the takeWhile function, this function stop to construct the list when the condition is false. Other than this, the behavior same as traverse function but only for Monad and list.

Modify the ns function add new parameter (Int->Bool) as condition, replace the second traverse function by traverseWhile as

```
ns :: Either String [[Int]]
      -> (Int -> Bool)
      -> (Int -> Either String Int)
      -> Either String [[Int]]
ns l c f = l >>= traverse (traverseWhile c f)
```

and resultFin, resultInf as

```
resultFin :: (Int->Bool)->Either String [[Int]]
resultFin c = ns dataFin c fun

resultInf :: (Int->Bool)->Either String [[Int]]
resultInf c = ns dataInf c fun
```

Now the resultInf behave as your temporary solution.

Furthermore, if negative number in the list after 5 as

```
ns (Right $ [[1..10] ++ [-1] ++ [1..]]) con fun
```

gives

> Right [[2,3,4]]

before 5

```
ns (Right $ [[1..2] ++ [-1] ++ [1..]]) con fun
```

gives

> Left "error"

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back. You're working with something of the shape

```
type Result e a = Either e [a]
```

Representing either an error condition or a (possibly infinite) list of elements. As you've seen, this is not the right shape for what you're trying to do. What you want, rather, is a list of elements that ends either successfully or not.

```
data SuccessStream e a
  = Cons a (SuccessStream e a)
  | Succeeded
  | Failed
```

There are several idiomatic ways to express this using common packages. Here's one option, using `streaming`.

```
import Streaming

type Result' e a = Stream (Of a) (Either e) ()
```

This gives you an easy "upgrade path" to streams with more interesting effects. For example:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

type Result'' e a = Stream (Of a) (ExceptT e IO) ()
```

And also to streams that return some final result.